# How to configure Rdesktop in Ubuntu with Unity?

Tags: unity, xrdp, rdesktop

In LXDE:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xrdp vino
vino-preferences

echo lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE > ~/.xsession

With Unity 3D???

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to connect to Unity Desktop using xrdp, you will need to have a vnc server that can support recomposing properly your desktop.

To be able to connect to Unity Desktop via xrdp, you will need to follow the following instructions guide   : http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962

In summary, You have to

1. install TigerVNC on your machine and then
2. install XRDP.
3. Finally, you tell your system that you want to use the Unity as preferred desktop and you should be good to go

Give it a try

Till next time